# Using increment inside of an "if" statement

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I ran into an issue today where the incrementer needed to be coded like this (inside of the `if` statement, and I had to use `&&` operators to get the correct result.  I could not use `for` or `foreach` to get the correct result. Is there a better way to write this?

```
if ($array[0]['key'] !== $var && $array[1]['key'] !== $var && $array[2]['key'] !== $var): ?>
  //echo something here
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the top-level index (in this case, `0`, `1`, or `2`) at which the max occurs **and** you want to search the whole array, you can use this combination of `array_search` and `array_column`:

```php
$array = [
    ['key' => 'foo'],
    ['key' => 'bar'],
    ['key' => 'baz'],
];

$var = 'hello world';

if (array_search($var, array_column($array, 'key')) === false) {
    echo 'var does not exist';
}
```

This method is [described in the PHP documentation here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#120784). Note, as I said above, this will NOT reliably give you the index if you care about it. I would only use it if you want to know whether or not the match exists.

If you want the index, or you specifically do not want to search beyond index 2 (or any other arbitrary index), you could make a function like this:

```php
$array = [
    ['key' => 'foo'],
    ['key' => 'bar'],
    ['key' => 'baz'],
];

$var = 'hello world';

function keyValueExists($array, $key, $value, $maxIndex = null) {
    foreach ($array as $index => $item) {
        if (isset($item[$key]) && $item[$key] === $value) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($maxIndex !== null && $index == $maxIndex) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

if (keyValueExists($array, 'key', $var, 2) === false) {
    echo 'var does not exist';
}
```